# Can my Typescript class have a typeguard method asserting a property is not null?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

Say I have a class that has a property that might be `null` or `undefined`:

```
class Pizza {
  constructor(
    public name:    string,
    public cheese?: string
  ) {}

  get hasCheese(): boolean {
    return !!this.cheese
  }
}
```

Now I want to operate on that possibly-null property downstream:

```
function eat(cheese: string) { ... }

function enjoy(pizza: Pizza) {
  return pizza.hasCheese && eat(pizza.cheese!)
}
```

(Obviously in this trivial case, `hasCheese` is silly and I can just test `pizza.cheese` directly; my real case is more complicated.)

Is there a way I can write a typeguard on `Pizza#hasCheese` here so that Typescript will recognize downstream that `pizza.cheese` is not null (so I don't have to use the `!` assertion)? I.e.,

```
class Pizza {
  ...
  get hasCheese(): boolean & this is {cheese: string} { // <- doesn't work
    return !!this.cheese
  }
}

function enjoy(pizza: Pizza) {
  return pizza.hasCheese && eat(pizza.cheese) // <- no ! operator
}
```

If `pizza.hasCheese` can't work, what about a `hasCheese()` method instead of a getter?

```
class Pizza {
  ...
  hasCheese(): boolean & this is {cheese: string} {
    return !!this.cheese
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't quite a [mre] because the class doesn't have a `cheese` property; the constructor takes such an argument but doesn't do anything with it.  Maybe you wanted them to be parameter properties like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mL5KvW)?  Could you [edit] to fix that so it's not distracting from your actual question?

Comment: Also, your question asks about a *method*, but you are using a *getter* (which is sort of a method but not what I'd call it).  You can certainly have a type guard *method* like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w1Azkw) shows, but there isn't any support currently for type guard *getters*; see feature request [ms/TS#43368](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43368).  (So you might want to [edit] to make clear if you want a method or a getter or either) Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz - edited to address both points. I would prefer the getter, but that's not the essential question -- I'll certainly take the method over nothing! (Please feel free to edit further as you see fit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript does not currently support annotating [property getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) as [user-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).  There's an open feature request for such support at [microsoft/TypeScript#43368](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43368).  It's marked as "awaiting more feedback", so if you want to see this implemented it wouldn't hurt to give it a  and describe your use case and why workarounds aren't sufficient.  It probably wouldn't *help* much either; there are a lot of open feature requests and the TS team couldn't possibly implement them all, even all the ones with significant community support.  But who knows?  Anyway, since we don't know when or even if this will ever be possible, you'll have to work around it.

---

One workaround that you mention as being acceptable is turning `hasCheese` into a [*method*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Method) instead of a getter.  You are indeed allowed to mark method return types as type predicates of the form `this is Type` where `Type` is known to be assignable to the instance type of the class.  Often to ensure this I'll write `this is this & Type` where the second utterance of `this` is the [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types), and by [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) it with `Type` we get something which is known to be assignable both to `this` and to `Type`.

In your case, it would be like this:

```
hasCheese(): this is this & { cheese: string } {
    return !!this.cheese
}
```

That compiles without error. Let's test it out:

```
function enjoy(pizza: Pizza) {
    eat(pizza.cheese); // error!
    //  ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    //  'string | undefined' is not assignable to 'string'

    pizza.hasCheese() && eat(pizza.cheese); // okay    
    // --------------------> ^^^^^
    // (parameter) pizza: Pizza & { cheese: string; }
}
```

Looks good.  The compiler now understands that checking `pizza.hasCheese()` has the effect of narrowing `pizza` from `Pizza` to `Pizza & {cheese: string}`, which is known to have a defined `cheese` property of type `string`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCWAvRZoG8CwAoavrAHsA7CAFwCcBXYUg8gCmz2egAdKAjEeYaIsALYBTAFzQy5eEQDmAGiYtc7Lj3wALIUIhCA-GIlTpC3AEp00AL7Zj0NZADCGrUPomxpNfBhfoHnwDJzYCdtfQpDS3QbZnIhUkpyImgAQmS-CAA6YM1tGyssfOssADNKIhp4YmghMFJ6bOcwyRkzNEsi0vLSSqShIgArAgBPelYkFDEEZDBWmxq6semskKETAG5oAHpN6vJyOmSbbdwAPzPzi7OjnegAcgMZaAAfaDKAEyFiqSE32+gfIgEUjQSAQeDSfhcIS+Ah3B7SW5FZiLFAZOwQRw5FxmfyBeajcZgZZY9ZbHYEADWYCGzGu0AAtIymcyWSyAHzQAB63O5dNGYHIgjiQnIZhRYEmhOggTaDVC4nCMg2+UKWCAA)

Answer (score 0):

You should correctly use type guards, and create new one for typing pizza with cheese, like this:

```
function pizzaWithCheese(pizza: Pizza): pizza is Pizza & Required<Pick<Pizza, 'cheese'>> {
    return pizza.hasCheese;
}
```

And then use it:

```
function enjoy(pizza: Pizza) {
  return pizzaWithCheese(pizza) && eat(pizza.cheese)
}
```